# Property Inheritance in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, properties

I want to inherit my base class properties and methods which will be used by my several derived classes. I want these properties and methods to be exactly protected so that they will only be visible in derived class and not to any external class. But it always gives me some errors.

```
@interface BasePerson : NSObject
@end

@interface BasePerson ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<Person*>* savedPersons;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldSavePerson;

@end



@interface DerivedPerson1 : BasePerson 

@end

@implementation DerivedPerson1

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.savedPersons = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.shouldSavePerson = NO;
    }

    return self;
}
```

It always gives me an error that

```
Property 'savedPersons' not found on object of type 'DerivedPerson1 *'
Property 'shouldSavePerson' not found on object of type 'DerivedPerson1 *'
```

How i can make use of inheritance in Objective C, I don't want savedPersons and shouldSavePerson properties to be visible to external classes. I only want them to visible in my base class and all the derived classes.

Any help will be great. Thanks

Comment: can you please let me know the parent class name of derived classes.
is it UIViewController or NSObject?

Comment: Its NSObject. Does that makes any difference?

Comment: Your code seems fine, does not yell error for me when compile

Comment: wow that great but seems that i am doing some thing wrong then

Comment: It works if the classes are in the same file!!! And this is what happened when someone copied you snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that the objectiveC really support. There are some ways though. So lets see.

If you put a property in the source file class extension then it is not exposed and you can not access it in the subclass either.

One way is to put all of the subclasses into the same source file as the base class. This is not a good solution at all as you do want to have separate files for separate classes.

It seems logical to import the `BaseClass.m` in the `SubClass` source file but that will produce a linker error saying that you have duplicate symbols.

**And the solution:**

Separate the extension into a separate header. So you have a `MyClass`

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@end
```

Source:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "MyClassProtected.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (void)foo {
    self.someProperty = @"Some text from base class";
}

@end
```

Then you create another header file (only the header) `MyClassProtected.h` which has the following:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someProperty;

@end
```

And the subclass `MyClassSubclass`

Header:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClassSubclass : MyClass

@end
```

And the source:

```
#import "MyClassSubclass.h"
#import "MyClassProtected.h"

@implementation MyClassSubclass

- (void)foo {
    self.someProperty = @"We can set it here as well";
}

@end
```

So now if the user `MyClassSubclass` he will not have the access to the protected property which is essentially what you want. But the downside is the user may still import `MyClassProtected.h` after which he will have the access to the property.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't have member access control for methods, but you can emulate it using header files.

**BasePerson.h**

```
@interface BasePerson : NSObject

    @property (strong,nonatomic) SomeClass *somePublicProperty;

    -(void) somePublicMethod;
 @end
```

**BasePerson-Private.h**

```
#import "BasePerson.h"

@interface BasePerson ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<Person*>* savedPersons;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldSavePerson;

@end
```

**BasePerson.m**

```
#import "BasePerson-Private.h"

...
```

**DerivedPerson1.h**

```
#import "BasePerson-Private.h"

@inteface DerivedPerson1 : BasePerson

 ...

@end
```

Now any class that #imports *BasePerson.h* will only see the public methods.  As I said though, this is only emulating access control since if a class #imports *BasePerson-Private.h" they will see the private members; this is just how C/Objective-C is.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve using @protected access specifier

```
@interface BasePerson : NSObject {
    @protected NSMutableArray *savedPersons;
    @protected BOOL shouldSavePerson;
    }
```

DerivedPerson1.m

---

```
@implementation DerivedPerson1

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self->savedPersons = [NSMutableArray array];
        self->shouldSavePerson = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

OtherClass.m

---

```
   #import "OtherClass.h"
    #import "BasePerson.h"

    @implementation OtherClass

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
        BasePerson *base = [[BasePerson alloc]init];
        base->savedPersons = @[];//Getting Error.  Because it is not a subclass.
    }

    @end
```